# console.log called by angular app not being displayed in browser console

Tags: angular, typescript, console

I call "console.log" in an angular component, but I don't see any log output in the firefox browser console, and also not in the window where I started it with "ng serve".

Where can I see the "console.log" output? Do I have to change my code? I know "console.log" is being called because I added other debug output after it.

The template:

```
<div class="card my-5">
  <div class="card-body">
    <form #carConfigurationForm="ngForm"  (change)="formChanged(carConfigurationForm)">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="extra">Extra 1&nbsp;</label>
        <select name="extra1" class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle" [(ngModel)]="extra1">
          <option value="default">Kein Extra</option>
          <option *ngFor="let extra of selectExtra" [value]="extra.id">{{extra.name}} {{extra.preis}}&euro;</option>
        </select>
      </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="gesamtpreis">Gesamt&nbsp;</label>
          <span name="gesamtpreis" [innerHTML]="gesamtpreis" ngModel="gesamtpreis"></span>
        </div>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

and the ts file:

```
import { Component, OnInit, OnChanges, Input } from '@angular/core';
import { Extra } from '../model/extra';
import { ExtraService} from '../service/extra.service';
import { SimpleChanges } from '@angular/core';
import { ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { FormControl, FormGroup } from '@angular/forms'
import { FormBuilder, Validators } from '@angular/forms'
@Component({
  selector: 'app-car-configuration-form',
  templateUrl: './car-configuration-form.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./car-configuration-form.component.sass']
})
export class CarConfigurationFormComponent implements OnInit, OnChanges {

  selectExtra : Extra[] = [];

  gesamtpreis : string = 'kein Preis';

  extraById = new Map<number,Extra>();

  constructor(private extraService: ExtraService, private formBuilder: FormBuilder) { }

  getSelectedExtra(): void{
    this.extraService.findAll()
      .subscribe(selectExtra => {
        this.selectExtra= selectExtra;
        this.selectExtra.forEach( (record : Extra)  => { this.extraById.set(record.id, record); });
        }
     );
  }

  // declare the variable referencing the ngForm
  @ViewChild('carConfigurationForm') carConfigurationForm: any;

  ngOnInit() {
    this.getSelectedExtra();
  }

  @Input() extra1: number = -1;

  formChanged(carConfigurationFormChanged : any) {
    this.gesamtpreis = "zzz8";
    console.log('zzz9 formChanged');
    this.gesamtpreis = JSON.stringify(this.extra1); // "2"
  }
}
```

Comment: That's probably because there's no `change` event on `form` at least I don't believe there's one. Someone can correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: I can't reproduce this in stackblitz:https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-bemvlw?file=src/app/app.component.ts when I enter something in the field and press enter, the console.log shows the change event.

Comment: Where is `console.log` in this code?

Comment: `console.log` is near the bottom, in formChanged. I know it is being called because setting `this.gesamtpreis` works.